# Is it possible to #define two words to some expression, not just a single word?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

If I want to replace all occurrences of `byte` with `unsigned char`, a simple `#define` will do it. Is there any way to do the reverse with a `#define`? Grouping two words with either single or double quotes doesn't work, nor escaping the space between them with a backslash. Is it even possible?

Comment: And I realise that I can `typedef unsigned char byte` to achieve the effect implied, but I'm interested in achieving `#define "foo bar" barfoo`... if only that were possible.

Comment: No, it must be an identifier. Perhaps with a real example of what you want to achieve, there's a better way.

Comment: I mostly wanted to rule out the possibility. I'm porting a bunch of code from linux/C to Windows/C++ for a quick spike down a possible development path. If the was possible, it would have made the difference between one change per header file and multiple. But I decided to phrase the question to shine light on a more general - and more interesting - question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The identifier in a `#define` statement cannot contain spaces, at least in C.

The controlling part of the C11 standard (though this is essentially the same in earlier iterations) is `6.10.3 Macro replacement /9-10` (combined below):

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>   `# define identifier replacement-list new-line`
>   `# define identifier lparen identifier-listopt ) replacement-list new-line`
>   `# define identifier lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line`
>   `# define identifier lparen identifier-list , ... ) replacement-list new-line`
>   blah blah blah ...

An `identifier` (as used in those directives) is specified in `6.4.2` of the same standard and does not list the space character as one of the allowed ones.

Answer (score 5):

The #define syntax is defined by

```
#define identifier token-string
```

So the middle part should be an identifier, which could not contain space.

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted answer is completely technically correct, it may not be immediately clear that the `#define` syntax given allows things like:

```
extern CString outputString;
#define printf( ... ) { CString temp; temp.Format( __VA_ARGS__ ); outputString += temp; }
```

The only elements you really need understand here are the `...` and the `__VA_ARGS__`. They represent a list of zero or more tokens. So this is a restricted example of where `#define` will interpret (but essentially ignore) spaces, and allow you to change multiple words into something different.

Although I've never done it myself, presumably if you have a function with default parameters, and calls to that function that appear to have a variable-length argument list (even though the true argument list is of fixed length) you can still use the `...` syntax and `__VA_ARGS__` to invoke a compatible function:

```
#define ThreeParamFunction( x, ... ) FiveParamFunction( foo, bar, (x), __VA_ARGS__ )
```